# using xslt in jsp

Tags: html, xml, jsp, xslt, jena

I want to apply xslt to my xml query results, but I keep receiving errors. I am working on Tomcat and my java code includes:

```
String ret="";
String xsltstylesheet = "https://dl.dropbox.com/x/xsltstylesheet.xsl";            
QueryExecution qExec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model) ;
ret += ResultSetFormatter.asXMLString(qExec.execSelect(), xsltstylesheet);   
qExec.close() ;    
return ret;
```

so having formatted my results as *XMLString*, I've been trying to produce html from it by using **1-transform** and **2-jstl** in my jsp but neither of cases is working:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/x/xsltstylesheet.xsl"?>
<%
   String search=request.getParameter("user");
   if(search==null) search="logic";
   String result=search;  
   try{
      ProjectMain pm=new ProjectMain();
      result=pm.different(search);
   }

//-case 1
   Source source = new StreamSource(${result}); // ?syntax error, misplaced constructor
   Source xsl = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/84745393/xsltstylesheet.xsl";
   Result table = new StreamResult(System.out);  
   StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl)); 
   Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);  
   t.transform(xsl, table);    

//-Or case 2
   < c:import url="${result}" var="xmldocument"/>//Multiple annotations found at this line, Syntax error, insert";" /on token">"/ on token "import"...
   < c:import url="https://dl.dropbox.com/x/xsltstylesheet.xsl" var="xslt"/> 
   < x:transform xml="${xmldocument}" xslt="${xslt}"/>    

   out.println(result);
%>
```

I guess my problem is that *transform* needs it's input in terms of StreamSource but mine is not. And I don't think I should write every instance of my query result in file to be able to convert it to html later.

What do people usually do? I don't know how to fix it.